# capture scrolling both horizontally and vertically

Tags: jquery

I have a simple div that scrolls both horizontally and vertically in its container.

Is it possible to capture when it scrolling horizontally and vertically so when it's scrolling horizontally console that and the same for vertically

```js
$(function(){
  $('.content').on('scroll', function() {
    console.log('scrolling up dpwn')
    $(this).scrollLeft(function(){
      console.log('scrolling left right')
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper{
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.content{
  height: 1000px; 
  width: 1000px;
  background: linear-gradient(-40deg, red 18%, red 48%, green 59%,#8fb3da 100%);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class="content">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just attached your event to the wrong place, and need to also do something with the scroll.

```js
  $('.wrapper').scroll(function(e) {
    $(this).scrollLeft($(this).scrollTop());
    $(this).scrollTop($(this).scrollLeft());
  });
```

```css
.wrapper{
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.content{
  height: 1000px; 
  width: 1000px;
  background: linear-gradient(-40deg, red 18%, red 48%, green 59%,#8fb3da 100%);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class="content">
    
  </div>
</div>
```